# Why a query in MongoDB is much more slow than the same query in MySQL?

Tags: mongodb

I made a little benchmark to compare MongoDB 3.4.4 and MySQL 5.7.18 on Ubuntu 16.04 server with 2 CPU, 16 GB RAM and SSD.

The benchmark was basically made on *contacts* collection/table with 50K documents/rows. The data is exactly the same in MongoDB collection and MySQL table, there are 150 fields but several of them with NULL value. I used a quite simple query in MongoDB (and the equivalent in MySQL) to measure the execution time of the same query on both DB engines.

The query in MongoDB:

```
db.contacts.find({
   parent_user_id: 1170, 
   shared_with: {$in: [0, 1175]},
   is_temporary: false, 
   app_scope: {$in: [1, 3]},
   company: {$regex: "lorem", $options: "i"}
}, {
   _id: 1,
   contact_name: 1, 
   email: 1, 
   tags: 1
}).
limit(50)
```

I also created an index to improve the query:

```
db.contacts.createIndex({
   parent_user_id: 1,   
   shared_with: 1, 
   is_temporary: 1, 
   app_scope: 1
}, {name: "base_and_sort_fields"})
```

Take in account the following:

- Discard adding the *company* field to the index as a possible solution.
- *company* field is never empty so the all 50K contacts have a company value.
- `$regex` condition is equivalent to `like '%lorem%'` in MySQL.
- I want to measure the execution time without caching any data so before executing the query I clean up MongoDB and WiredTiger caches restarting the mongod service and clean up the filesystem cache using: `sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
- I made several optimizations on OS before the benchmark according to official [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-checklist-operations/#linux) but it was not so different from the benchmark with no optimization. I did no optimization on MySQL 5.7.18.
- I repeated the benchmark dozens of times getting the same result.

The query takes about 4 seconds to finish in MongoDB whereas MySQL only takes about 200 millisecond. See the output of the query explain in MongoDB to confirm that the index is used to execute the query (stage: IXSCAN):

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 50,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 4192,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 2898,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 2896,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "nReturned" : 50,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1739,
            "works" : 2899,
            "advanced" : 50,
            "needTime" : 2848,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 219,
            "restoreState" : 219,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "limitAmount" : 50,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                "nReturned" : 50,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1739,
                "works" : 2898,
                "advanced" : 50,
                "needTime" : 2848,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 219,
                "restoreState" : 219,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "transformBy" : {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "contact_name" : 1,
                    "email" : 1,
                    "tags" : 1
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "company" : {
                            "$regex" : "lorem",
                            "$options" : "i"
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 50,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1739,
                    "works" : 2898,
                    "advanced" : 50,
                    "needTime" : 2848,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 219,
                    "restoreState" : 219,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 2896,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 2896,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                        "works" : 2898,
                        "advanced" : 2896,
                        "needTime" : 2,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 219,
                        "restoreState" : 219,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "parent_user_id" : 1,
                            "shared_with" : 1,
                            "is_temporary" : 1,
                            "app_scope" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "base_and_sort_fields",
                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "parent_user_id" : [ ],
                            "shared_with" : [
                                "shared_with"
                            ],
                            "is_temporary" : [ ],
                            "app_scope" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "parent_user_id" : [
                                "[1170.0, 1170.0]"
                            ],
                            "shared_with" : [
                                "[0.0, 0.0]",
                                "[1175.0, 1175.0]"
                            ],
                            "is_temporary" : [
                                "[false, false]"
                            ],
                            "app_scope" : [
                                "[1.0, 1.0]",
                                "[3.0, 3.0]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 2898,
                        "seeks" : 3,
                        "dupsTested" : 2896,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Why is MongoDB so slow compared to MySQL?**

**Am I missing something?**

**What can I do to become the MongoDB query as fast as MySQL one?**

FYI: The MySQL query is even more complex because in order to get the tags per contact, it needs to join with two more tables then group by contact ID.

Comment: Can you add the `queryPlanner` section of `cursor.explain("executionStats")`?

Comment: @str for the sake of simplicity I didn't put the whole queryPlanner output. I have others indexes with the same prefix (parent_user_id,  shared_with, is_temporary, app_scope) plus other fields so MongoDB is choosing the right index. However if you really need that output after this explanation, I will added. Let me know. Thanks!